# NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex: problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, insert, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with this method. I have eleven images with this names: Articulo 1.png, Articulo 2.png, etc. I dont know why , but my array of images only has the last image. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my example:

```
NSMutableArray imagenesA = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
NSMutableString *name = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *name2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)  {

    name = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Articulo %d.png",y+1];
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    name2 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Articulo %d",y+1];
    [dict  setObject:name2  forKey:@"nombre"];
    [dict  setObject:imageView forKey:@"imagen"];

    [imagenesA insertObject:dict atIndex:y];

    // show all dictionarys
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", dict);
}

// show index 0 element --> must be Articulo 1 but...
NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                    initWithDictionary:[imagenesA objectAtIndex:0]]; 
NSLog(@"*********************%@***********************",d);
```

---

Console response:

> 2011-08-20 14:26:47.411 Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 1"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.411
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 2"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.412
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 3"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.412
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 4"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.413
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 5"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.414
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 6"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.414
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 7"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.415
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 8"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.415
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 9"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.416
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 10"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.416
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] DICT: {
>       imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 11"; } 2011-08-20 14:26:47.416
>   Catalogo-V1[28155:207] ********************{
>       **imagen = ">";
>       nombre = "Articulo 11";** }**********************

Comment: In the loop, you are inserting the *same* dictionary to the array over and over and, in every iteration, you are *replacing* the objects for the keys `nombre` and `imagen`.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing but that's ugly! Paid attention to the memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. @albertamg is correct in his comment above. Your `for` loop should look like the following.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)  {

    // Other codes here

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict  setObject:name2  forKey:@"nombre"];
    [dict  setObject:imageView forKey:@"imagen"];
    [imagenesA insertObject:dict atIndex:y];
}
```